# Is there a way to use a library in a bookmarklet?

Tags: javascript, momentjs, bookmarklet

I want to use `moment.js` (http://momentjs.com/) in my bookmarklet, but I have never used a library and am unsure how I would go about adding it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why do you need to use moment.js in a bookmarklet? (you'd need to add it to the current page's DOM using a script tag, which can be done in javascript)

Comment: @JaromandaX I am creating a bookmarklet that creates a countdown to the end of the current period for my school, and it uses moment.js. also, what would I like the script tag too?